# How to update a drop down?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I have a drop box ("drpstatus") that sets another dropbox ("drpReason").

"drpstatus" is either "A" or "D" if it's "A" I need to change it to "D".

When I do it manually it updates my "drpReason" drop down from list "A" to list "D" but when I change it programmatically "drpReason" stays on list "A" despite the value now being "D" so the "20375" value I'm looking for isn't there.

I can't refresh the page it will clear the boxes.

I am using this loop for testing.

```
If wd.document.getElementById("drpStatus").Value = "A" Then
    wd.document.getElementById("drpStatus").Value = "D"

'I assume i'm missing something here to repopulate the "drpReason" dropbox

    Do Until wd.document.getElementById("drpReason").Value = "20375"
        DoEvents
        wd.document.getElementById("drpReason").Value = "20375"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Loop
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added what i needed below right where I thought I needed code.

```
If wd.document.getElementById("drpStatus").Value = "A" Then
    wd.document.getElementById("drpStatus").Value = "D"

wd.document.getElementById("drpStatus").FireEvent ("onchange")

        Do Until wd.document.getElementById("drpReason").Value = "20375"
        DoEvents
        wd.document.getElementById("drpReason").Value = "20375"
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Loop
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.